# I have a problem with this question: building a function called findFirstWordWithMostRepeatedChars

Tags: javascript

**Problem statement :**

Write a function that finds Max Repeat count In Word. Looks like there is a problem with loops

```js
// Skeleton

// FUNCTION DEFINITION(S)
function findMaxRepeatCountInWord(word) {
  // Break up individual word into individual letters.
  word = word.split('');
  // Count the instances of each letter
  let objOfLetters = {};
  for (let i = 0; word.length; i++) {
    //if word[i] is not exist in objOfLetters
    if (objOfLetters[word[i]] === undefined) {
      //creat an an prop with key set to word at i and value set to 1
      objOfLetters[word[i]] = 1;
      //otherwize
    } else {
      //add 1 to its value
      objOfLetters[word[i]]++;
    }

  }
  // getting all the valuse that are the counts of letters
  let counts = Object.values(objOfLetters);
  let max = counts[0];
  for (let k = 1; k < counts.length; k++) {
    if (counts[k] > max) {
      max = counts[k];
    }
  }
  return max;
}

// ASSERTION FUNCTION(S) TO BE USED

function assertEqual(actual, expected, testName) {
  if (actual === expected) {
    console.log('passed');
  } else {
    console.log('FAILED [' + testName + '] Expected ' + expected + ', but got ' + actual);
  }
}

var input_1 = 'passed';
var actual_1 = findMaxRepeatCountInWord(input_1);
var expected_1 = 2;
assertEqual(actual_1, expected_1, 'it shows that how many times a characters repeated');
```

Can someone help me on this ?

Comment: [my codes don't work](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) isn't a useful description of the problem

Comment: For some reason I feel, for names this long like `findMaxRepeatCountInWord`, snake case is more suitable than camel case. `find_max_repeat_count_in_word`, see that reads more clear than `findMaxRepeatCountInWord`... Just a thought...

Comment: shall an alternative implementation work for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be the for loop end condition. You have this:

```
for (let i = 0; word.length; i++) {
```

Instead of this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
```

Comment: Thank you. I was very tired and I never thought the problem would be like this.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function find_max_repeat_count_in_word(word) {
  const chars = word && word.split('').filter(char => (char || '').trim()) || [];
  let counterMap = {};
  let max = 0;
  // max value can be tracked along side building the counter map
  chars.forEach(char => {
    counterMap = {...counterMap, [char]: (counterMap[char] || 0) + 1 };
    if (counterMap[char] > max) {
      max = counterMap[char];
    }
  });
  return max;
}
```

---

### **Considerations**

> It doesn't take into consideration whitespaces

> Since expected is just max, it doesn't matter if two or more characters have same count

---

### ***Illustration***

```js
function find_max_repeat_count_in_word(word) {
  const chars = word && word.split('').filter(char => (char || '').trim()) || [];
  let counterMap = {};
  let max = 0;
  // max value can be tracked along side building the counter map
  chars.forEach(char => {
    counterMap = {...counterMap, [char]: (counterMap[char] || 0) + 1 };
    if (counterMap[char] > max) {
      max = counterMap[char];
    }
  });
  return max;
}

console.log('[Input]', undefined, '[Output]', find_max_repeat_count_in_word(undefined));
console.log('[Input]', null, '[Output]', find_max_repeat_count_in_word(null));
console.log('[Input]', '\'\'', '[Output]', find_max_repeat_count_in_word(''));
console.log('[Input]', '\'undefined\'', '[Output]', find_max_repeat_count_in_word('undefined'));
console.log('[Input]', 'Hello', '[Output]', find_max_repeat_count_in_word('Hello'));
console.log('[Input]', 'passive', '[Output]', find_max_repeat_count_in_word('passive'));
console.log('[Input]', 'possessive postman', '[Output]', find_max_repeat_count_in_word('possessive postman'));
console.log('[Input]', 'Do something with          previous     code, it seems to be running in infinite loop', '[Output]', find_max_repeat_count_in_word('Do something with          previous     code, it seems to be running in infinite loop'));
```

---

### ***`WYSIWYG`*** => ***`WHAT YOU SHOW IS WHAT YOU GET`***

Answer (score 0):

The exit condition of the for loop is not written correctly.

You can correct by writing : `for(let i = 0; i < word.length; i++)`

otherwise the `word.length` condition will always be true.

Comment: Thank you. I was very tired and I never thought the problem would be like this.